# Repairing a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I'm fixing a polymorphic association that was 'kind of' set up in the past. Here are the details.

```
User.rb has fields:
user_type_id
user_type
```

I need `User` to belong to `Company` or `Employee`.

The problem I'm having is because the User.rb fields are not named using Rails convention (something like `usable_type` and `usable_id`). How can I set up the association given the fields I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an undocumented `:foreign_type` option on `belongs_to`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_type, :polymorphic => true, :foreign_type => 'user_type'
end
```

Comment: I cannot get the opposite associations to work - how do you do the equivalent `has_one`?

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to change the names of the fields to suit the Rails convention: since the polymorphic association is not properly set up yet, and those fields should not be used for anything else, so you should not have a problem.

Essentially you need to choose a name `xyz` to suit the following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :xyz, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :as => :xyz
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :as => :xyz
end
```

where your user model has fields

```
User
xyz_id    :integer
xyz_type    :string
```

This will also make for more maintainable code later on.